# Coldfusion - ORM removing child objects

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I'm trying to nail down the specifics of removing a child in an one-to-many relationship in CF using ORM.  I've posted a small test app here:

https://github.com/pnahtanoj/cfrelationship

Regarding the removeChildren() function on ln47 of create.cfm - if I dump the parent object before and after, I see that the children have been removed.  However, they are still in the DB after the close of the transaction.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Using CF10, MySql 5.something...

Answer (score 0):

Because you set inverse to true on the many side, that means only the child side is tracked by Hibernate.

You can set all the child's parent to null.

```
public void function removeChildren() {
    transaction {
      var children = getChilds();
      for (var c in children)
          c.setParent( javacast('null','') );
    }

    arrayClear(variables.childs);
}
```

Comment: I think the inverse='true' is in the right place, per Whish's book on CF ORM.  I finally got it working with this definition:      property 
        name="Childs" 
        type="array" 
        fieldtype="one-to-many" 
        cfc="Child" 
        singularname="Child" 
        fkcolumn="ParentID"
        cascade="all-delete-orphan"
        inverse="true";